# What is an opaque byte string?

Tags: c++, c, string

I've been gooling for a while, but I found nothing too helpful. What is an opaque byte string and what would be a c/c++ example of it ?

**Update**
A little more context, from rfc5001

*2.3.  The NSID Option
   The OPTION-CODE for the NSID option is 3.
   The OPTION-DATA for the NSID option is an **opaque byte string**, the
   semantics of which are deliberately left outside the protocol.  See
   Section 3.1 for discussion.*

Comment: Perhaps it depends on the context? Maybe it means this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type. This data type is referenced by this: http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1832/index.htm and there is a wiki page about XDR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation. If someone agrees, feel free to post an answer with this info, I won't mind. btw, I found this by googling...

Comment: What did "Section 3.1" say about it

Comment: @Tomalak Implementation details are left open

Comment: @sjobe: Pretty short subsection

Comment: @Tomalak Well there is more to it, but I'm sure you can find the whole text.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They probably mean a byte array of unspecified format. By "opaque" they mean that the inner structure exists, but is unknown. So the program is expected to treat the string as a whole - store it, transmit it, but not try to interpret.

The C++ example would be an instance of `std::vector<unsigned char>`. A C example would be an array of unsigned char (either dynamic AKA `malloc`'ated or static).

Answer (score 4):

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2608:

> Opaque values are sequences of bytes. These are distinguished from Strings since they begin with the sequence "\FF". This, unescaped, is an illegal UTF-8 encoding, indicating that what follows is a sequence of bytes expressed in escape notation which constitute the binary value. For example, a '0' byte is encoded "\FF\00".